# Add code within script tags if script contains certain string with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

With preg_replace I want to modify all occurring inline javascript (within script tags) on a HTML page if the script **contains 'jQuery'** and it **doesn't contain 'defer'**. The modification is to add extra script around the existing script.

So for example this is (part of) the HTML output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//Should not match, because of 'defer'
    function defer(method) {
        if (window.jQuery) {
            method();
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() { defer(method) }, 50);
        }
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">//Should match because of 'jQuery'
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        //some code
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">//Should not match, because of no 'jQuery'
    window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl"....."}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">//Should match because of 'jQuery' further down within the script tag
    if(typeof gf_global == 'undefined') //some other code
    jQuery(document).bind(function(){
        //some code
    });
</script>
```

For now I've come to this:

```
$buffer = preg_replace('#<script type="text\/javascript">(.*?jQuery.*?)<\/script>#is', '<script type="text/javascript">/*Additional code around it*/$1/*Additional code*/</script>', $buffer);
```

However when jQuery doesn't occur within the script tags, the rest of the HTML is also taken in account until 'jQuery.../script>' occurs.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution (it's tested):

```
$html_segment = "your html part with multiple script tags";
$insert_before ="<script to put BEFORE><br/>";
$insert_after = "<br/><script to put AFTER>";
$avoid_tag = "defer";
$search_tag ="jQuery";
//
$temp = explode("<script", $html_segment);
$result = "";
$len = count($temp);
for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
  $part = $temp[$i];
  // check if this part contains 'jQuery'
  // and does NOT contain 'defer'
  // if not -> do something
  if (strpos($part, $search_tag) !== false &&
      strpos($part, $avoid_tag) === false) {
    // change
    $part = $insert_before."<script".$part;
    $part = str_replace("</script>", "</script>$insert_after", $part);
  } else if ($i >0) {
    // put back the original
    $part = "<script".$part;
  }
  $result.=$part;
}
//END: $result now has the new HTML
// proof:
echo "<textarea>$result</textarea>";
//
```

Comment: Happy to hear this :) it's not regex, but you can easily adapt it for other uses.